# Can you manage custom process templates across Organizations in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/process-templates/customize-process?view=azure-devops) goes into how customize process template using inherited process templates. I'd like to spread my customized process templates across Organizations. Is this possible?

If not, is there a workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a REST API for process templates. At the moment that's your best bet to export templates and to import them into other organizations. There is no "cross org sync" and no "process template marketplace" or "process template extension" support at the moment.

- [Import Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/processadmin/processes/import%20process%20template?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0)
- [Export Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/processadmin/processes/export%20process%20template?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0)

There is an [Azure Pipelines set of tasks available through this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nkdagility.processtemplate) which can help you to keep track of your process customizations and sync them across orgs.

The Inherited processes are [imported/exported using this Microsoft NPM package](https://github.com/Microsoft/process-migrator). If you have a recent version of NodeJS/npm installed, you can simply run:

```
npx process-migrator
```

to get started.